# make sure Fortran common variables are initialized to zero in a third-party library

Tags: fortran

I am using an old Fortran library from C++. This library has `debug.h` where a number of common block `int` variables are defined that are used throughout the library to control terminal output.

The issue is that when I compile this library with gfortran 4.8.5 on a HPC cluster, those common block variables are not zero. Whereas I have no issues with them on macOS or Ubuntu with gfortran 7.2.0.

Since I don't use Fortran at all (I call Fortran functions from C++), the only explanation I can think of is that those variables are not initialized to zero.

Is there a way I can double check they are indeed initialized to zero or force them to always be initialized to zero?

Comment: Example code would help a lot. We can't reproduce your problem without it.

Comment: Fortran variables are NOT by default initialized to anything. I believe C++ is the same. See `-finit-real`.

Comment: i can't give an example, but here's the header I was speaking about https://github.com/opencollab/arpack-ng/blob/master/PARPACK/SRC/MPI/debug.h

Comment: @VladimirF I know how it works in C++, but I don't understand how those common variables would work in Fortran as there is really no place where those are set to anything (I `grep`-ed)

Comment: you could just assign them all to zero at the start of the top level functions you call from c.

Comment: @agentp i was trying to do this with various ways, but could not figure out how to access and set common block vars from C++ **library**. The linking structure is: myProgram -> C++ lib -> Fortran lib.

Comment: I meant modify the fortran source to to the library to do the initialization. BTW at  a glance that github link looks to be active. Had you tried asking the developers for the best approach?

Comment: @agentp yes, I let maintainers know about the problem. Hopefully me (or somebody else) will fix this eventually. p.s. AFAIK the repo is the community effort to maintain the original library abandoned more than 10 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortran variables are not set to any value by themselves unless you use the DATA statement (inside BLOCK DATA for COMMON blocks) or Fortran 90+ initialization. Their value is undefined until you assign a value to them in your code.

You can use a compiler-specific option of GCC

```
-finit-real=zero
-finit-integer=0
```

to set initial values to variables. Better double check it indeed includes COMMON blocks.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html

Comment: For objects in COMMON you will also have to use BLOCK DATA to initialise them. I apologise to readers of a nervous disposition for the use of such crude language.

Comment: can you please elaborate on "For objects in COMMON you will also have to use BLOCK DATA to initialise them."? I am not a fortran user

Comment: BLOCK DATA is a special subrogam (actually a block-data program unit) that initializes a COMMON block https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn7l/index.html Something I never use in practice so I forgot it here.

Comment: Vladimir is quite correct when he says Fortran variables are never initialised, unlike static variables in C (and I assume C++, by extrapolation). Instead in Fortran 77 and earlier you had to use Data statements to perform the initialisation. Common Block, being of global scope, had their own special rules compared to local variables, and one is that the initialisation had to occur in a special subprogram type called Block Data. You can find an example at https://www.obliquity.com/computer/fortran/common.html. This is now totally archaic and totally superseded by modules.

Comment: @IanBush thanks for clarification. To make it closer to the reality, what can one do with that archaic Fortran library to make sure those common variables are initialized? Keep in mind that I only link against this lib and use it from C++, I compile no Fortran files.

Comment: You can create the block data and link together with the library. Or study how to initialize the Fortran library properly. Or submit a bug repo to the authors. Or do nothing...