Function that evaluates number of array elements that have been given a value
I've defined an n-element array
Then, depending on the fulfillment or not of some conditions, some of those elements are given a value. Some not.
Is there a fortran function that returns the number of array elements that have been given a value? Suppose that the function in question is called nelements. Then,
integer*4 i
dimension i(50)
i(1) = 7
i(2) = 15
write(6,*)"number of array elements that have been given a value ", nelements(i)
end

would render 2 since only 2 elements of the array i have been defined. Is there a function like that in fortran, or a workaround ?

My general comments in another answer apply. You cannot determine, in Fortran, whether any particular subobject (element of an array) has been defined.

I'm inclined to suggest that this is a duplicate of that other question. If you feel that question and its answer doesn't address your question here, can you make that more clear? See also this other question.

While as @francescalus says you can't do that directly in standard Fortran in this particular case it may be possible to work around it by, when you set up the array, filling the arrays with a value you know can not be valid (e.g. negative if you know the numbers should be positive) and then once you have filled in what you need finding which of those invalid values remain. Also note integer*4 is not standard Fortran, has never been standard Fortran, and may not be supported by all compilers - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618317/make-sure-fortran-common-variables-are-initialized-to-zero-in-a-third-party-libr

Ugh. Please do NOT use compiler flags to initialize vars, prefer the other methods mentioned.

Or declare a separate array of logicals like is_initialized and start it .false.. Fortran may not have this capability baked in, but it is easy to replicate.
